# React Native How can I put one view in front of the other

Tags: react-native, css-position, absolute

**I have an View in front of the another View in my React Native code, I would like to change it.**

**How can I do this?**

**I tried put position absolute but, it do not works.**

**Do you have a tip?**

**Code JSX Bellow: **

O Do not know what I Can Tell To You, Stack OverFlow Do not Know About it.

```
<PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={animatedEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChanged}>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            height: 90,
            width: 90,
            backgroundColor: '#8CC63F',
            borderRadius: 50,
            marginTop: 200,
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: translateX.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [-120, 0, 120],
                  outputRange: [-100, 0, 120],
                  extrapolate: 'clamp',
                }),
              },
            ],
          }}>
          <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              style={styles.iconContainer}
              name="racing-helmet"
              size={36}
              color="#fff"
            />
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
      <View style={styles.iconsNavigation}>
        <MaterialIcons
          style={styles.iconSpace}
          name="cancel"
          size={30}
          color="#707070"
        />
        <MaterialIcons
          style={styles.iconSpace}
          name="check-circle"
          size={30}
          color="#8CC63F"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
```

Style Code Bellow:

```
   iconContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 12,
  },
  iconsNavigation: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  iconSpace: {
    paddingHorizontal: 125,
    bottom: 60,
  },[![View in front of the other][1]][1]
```

[image: Image front]
                                             j dd              dddddddddd
ssxsxaaxxasxsasssssssssssssssscsccdcdcdccdcdcdcdcddcddcddcdc

Comment: Please post only relevant code instead of posting whole code. I'd advise you to edit your code in the question with only relevant pieces.

Comment: thats ok!!, I do this

Comment: Can anyone help me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using zIndex for example:

```
    <View id="top" style={{width: 100, height: 100, zIndex:2, backgroundColor: 'white'}} />
    <View id="bottom" style={{width: 100, height: 100, zIndex:1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
```

By running this the white View with id="top" will be in the front. Now you can use this **zIndex** style property in your code.